# button true / false cyclic

Tags: angular, typescript

As I can do for the next button when I press it, I return a `true` state and when I press it again it returns a `false` state and so on.

**myComponent.html**

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" (click)="actualizarEstado()">Editar</button>
```

**myComponent.ts**

```
actualizarEstado(){
  estado: false
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways for making it

**1st method from controller**

> app.component.html

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" (click)="actualizarEstado()">Editor</button>
```

> Controller

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
 selector: 'my-app',
 templateUrl: './app.component.html',
 styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})

 export class AppComponent  {
 public estado : boolean = false;

  actualizarEstado(){
   return this.estado = !this.estado;
  }
}
```

**2st method from view level**

> app.component.html

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm"(click)="estado=!estado">Editor</button>
```

> Controller

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
 selector: 'my-app',
 templateUrl: './app.component.html',
 styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})

 export class AppComponent  {
  public estado : boolean = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can do it shortly:** 
In your component:

```
estado:boolean=false;
```

In your html:

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm"(click)="estado=!estado">Editar</button>
```

**Note:**
when you want to declare parameter in typescript you have to do it like this:
`nameOfParameter` then `:` and the `type` then you have to initialize the parameter with `=`
*like this:*
`nameOfParameter:type=something`

Answer (score 0):

In your component intialize estado with false value then write below function to get cyclic true/false value as you looking for,

```
mycomponent.ts
estado : boolean = false;

actualizarEstado(){
  return this.estado = !this.estado;
}
```